# Some specifice range of date not sorting in Ionic typeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Date b/w 26 April 2020 to 30 April 2020 is not sorting properly weird ahh okay..

1) I am having a array like

```
[
  {
    "dateAndTime": "05/05/2020 09:00:00"
  },
  {
    "dateAndTime": "26/04/2020 09:00:00"
  },
  {
    "dateAndTime": "25/05/2020 09:00:00"
  }
]
```

2) Sorting code

```
         this.myArray.sort((a: MyDateClass ,b: MyDateClass) => (b.dateAndTime <= a.dateAndTime ? -1 : 1) );
```

3) export class

```
export class MyDateClass {
 public dateAndTime: Date;
}
```

4) Expected output

```
25/05/2020 09:00:00
05/05/2020 09:00:00
26/04/2020 09:00:00
```

5) Getting output

```
26/04/2020 09:00:00
05/05/2020 09:00:00
05/05/2020 09:00:00
```

Some extra cases if I include array date **28,29,26,27,30** April it will sorting right like *26,27,28,29,30*

What is wrong with specific range of date b/w 26 to 30 April ?

**Note:** *This is Ionic 3 and this issue tested in safari, Firefox, Chrome*

**Updating** I also try below mention possible solution but latest time not sorting.

```
 let data=[ { "dateAndTime": "05/04/2020 09:00:00" }, { "dateAndTime": "05/04/2020 09:10:00" }, { "dateAndTime": "05/04/2020 09:09:22" },{ "dateAndTime": "05/05/2020 09:00:00" }, { "dateAndTime": "05/05/2020 09:09:22" }];
let result =  data.sort((a,b) => {
  let aa = new Date(a.dateAndTime.slice(0,10).split('/').reverse().join('/'));
  let bb = new Date(b.dateAndTime.slice(0,10).split('/').reverse().join('/'));
  return (bb <= aa ? -1 : 1);
  // return (aa <= bb ? 1 : -1);
});
console.log('Sorted___', result);
```

**Output**

```
0: Object { dateAndTime: "05/05/2020 09:00:00" }

1: Object { dateAndTime: "05/05/2020 09:09:22" } //This will be come at place of object 0:first

2: Object { dateAndTime: "05/04/2020 09:00:00" }

3: Object { dateAndTime: "05/04/2020 09:10:00" }  // here this will be come at place of object 2:

4: Object { dateAndTime: "05/04/2020 09:09:22" }
```

Comment: You couldn't sort them because they are strings, not dates. Unfortunately, the date format is not suitable for JS Date parser, you need to alter your sort logic and parse manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is due to invalid date

```js
var data=[{ "dateAndTime": "05/04/2020 09:00:00" },{ "dateAndTime": "05/04/2020 09:10:00" },{ "dateAndTime": "05/04/2020 09:09:22" }, { "dateAndTime": "05/05/2020 09:00:00" }, { "dateAndTime": "05/05/2020 09:09:22" }];

result = data.sort((a,b)=>{
  aa = new Date(a.dateAndTime.slice(0,10).split('/').reverse().join('/') + a.dateAndTime.slice(10));
  bb = new Date(b.dateAndTime.slice(0,10).split('/').reverse().join('/') + b.dateAndTime.slice(10));
  return bb - aa;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine "return ( bb <=  aa ? -1 : 1)", But now Date vise sorting is working like charm but in case of time it's not sorting, It should be sort according to latest time ?

Comment: @Rajat.r2 You need `April data` first, is it so?

Comment: Yes, "26/04/2020 09:00:00", "26/04/2020 09:00:01", According to latest and bigest time the second date come first place.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I updated my question , not achieved please help I am stuck.

Comment: @Rajat.r2, we were slicing out the time part that's why it was not working, I have updated the answer.